# How to call super methods defined in a serial of modules in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, module, super

Is it possible to make c1.say to show "lalala" without changing M1, M2, C1? I.e., use extra modules to override M2's method? Thanks,

```
module M1
  def word
    "lalala"
  end
end

module M2
  def word
    super + 'wawawa'
  end
end

class C1
  include M1
  include M2
  def say
    puts word
  end
end

c1 = C1.new
c1.say # lalalawawawa
```

Comment: That's a weird requirement. Do you have a real world application for it?

Comment: In fact, M1, M2 and C1 are all modules and class in Rails, we try to override M2's methods which have super inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always monkey-patch any class without changing its original code.

```
module M1
  def word
    "lalala"
  end
end

module M2
  def word
    super + 'wawawa'
  end
end

class C1
  include M1
  include M2
  def say
    puts word
  end
end

# patch M2
M2.class_eval do
  def word
    super
  end
end

# or patch C1
# C1.class_eval do
#   def word
#     'lalala'
#   end
# end


c1 = C1.new
c1.say
# >> lalala
```

Comment: But we want to keep the super method behavior, i.e., we need to call the "super"...